# Oracle Apex- Branch to another page based on PL/SQL function body

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a "Registration" page and in that page I put a submit button. When the submit button is clicked, if the the registration is successful, I want it to redirect the page to "Success" page.

To achieve this I made a "Branch" where the "Branch Action" is a PL/SQL function body returning the page number that I want it to redirect. **The function body is:**

```
if (select count(username) from tuser_info where upper(username) = upper(:p2_username) > 0) 
then return '3';
else return '4';
```

**But this block is giving this error:**

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 49: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date 'a string literal with character set specification' 'a number' 'a single-quoted SQL string' pipe 'an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set s

**Could anyone help me solve this problem???**

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem finally.

There are some errors in my PL/SQL function body. It should be:

```
declare
    total number;
begin
    total := 0;
    select count(username) into total from tuser_info where upper(username) = upper(:p2_username);
    if (total > 0) then return '3';
    else return '4';
    end if;
end;
```